# How can I define props?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I've seen props being define like:

```
props: ['message', 'name', 'something']
```

and

```
props: {
    imperfectNumber: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
      }
 }
```

Whats the difference and how can I define some props that require no validation and others that do all in the same block?

Comment: You would do well to read through the documentation based on the last two questions. Both of them are covered. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Prop-Validation

Comment: I've read the docs, it does not answer either of my questions.

Comment: It absolutely does.

Comment: Where does it show how to use the string and object versions together?

Comment: Once you go down the object definition route, you have to do that with all the props. You can't mix them.

Comment: Thanks webnoob finally an answer o a simple question. Post it and il accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you go down the object definition route, you have to do that with all the props. You can't mix them.

You can find more information about the props here:  https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Prop-Validation

Note:

> **Instead** of defining the props as an array of strings, you can use an
> object with validation requirements

I've highlighted the part in the manual that explains. This indicates you can do one or the other.